# Index duplicate rows in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a column to index duplicate rows and order by another column.
Here's the example dataset:
`df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' = ['A','A','A','B','B','B','B'], 'Score'=[9,10,10,8,7,8,8], 'Year'=[2019,2018,2017,2019,2018,2017,2016']})`
I want to use ['Name', 'Score'] for identifying duplicates. Then index the duplicate order by Year to get following result:

[image]

Here rows 2 and 3 are duplicate rows because they have same name and score, so I order them by year and give index.
Is anyone have good idea to realize this in Python? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `cumcount`:

```
df['Index'] = (df.sort_values('Year', ascending=False)
   .groupby(['Name','Score'])
   .cumcount() + 1
)
```

Output:

```
  Name  Score  Year  Index
0    A      9  2019      1
1    A     10  2018      1
2    A     10  2017      2
3    B      8  2019      1
4    B      7  2018      1
5    B      8  2017      2
6    B      8  2016      3
```